# Skeleton bone in incorrect spot in-game yet, blender rig, skeleton mesh and physics asset are all correct and behave properly

Tags: physics, unreal-4, mesh, skeletal-animation, blueprints

I've made a custom character and rigged it in blender. Then exported/imported into ue4. It behaves properly in the PHAT and the skeleton mesh looks fine and it all behaves properly in the simulations.

In the BP and in-game the physics all behave fine except 1 single bone rises above the rest and appears to "flip" the root bone for unknown reasons. Almost like all the sudden the root does a 180 and then one specific bone attached rises as a result, not sure if it rises and that flips the root or the root is flipping for some unknown reason.

What I don't understand is why everything is fine *until* it is in-game/bp. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how physics work with skeleton mesh?

[image]

I've been banging my head on the wall trying to figure out phat, skeletons and how physics work in ue4 for about a month now and there is basically 0 docs/tutorials on this. As much as I love being stuck on this problem forever if anyone has an idea on what is going wrong that'd be great.

Comment: Is it possible that you didn't set scale of your model to 1.1.1 in the program you are using?

Comment: I use blender but yeah the scales are all setup correctly and everything.

Comment: I completely remade him in blender and made sure everything is correct. Bone rolls, import scaling, bone names/orientation. It is all good. I've deleted the old one from my project and did a new import.

Remade the phat sim and setup the bodies and constraints and it behaves perfectly fine in editor and on simulation but in play that bone is still raised.

Comment: Have you tried changing some of the hierarchy names? Sometimes things get better when uou change name from "root" to literally anything else. Try with things like "root" and "armature"

Comment: My hierarchy has the armature named root and then all bones come from that. IF their is a better way to name things I'd love to be enlightened as to what my name system should be..

Comment: There's no objectively better naming convention. But (and my memory can play tricks on me) the main object is called something like "root" or "armature" in blender, UE4 will make a hiss about it and everything will be... weird.

After I renamed it to something clear enough, but different, like "Skele", it worked fine. From what I know, UE4 tries to make it's own base object named one of those keywords, and that causes issues.

Comment: So should I then name my armature to something random and then in ue4 it would just change it to root?

Comment: No, it's different than that. Just try doing what I described. Rename the element and then import to UE4 to see if it works better.